# Should super keyword get access to private fields and methods. I am able to get access to private methods and fields

Tags: java

I have two inner classes A,B and B is a subclass of A. I am trying to access
private methods and fields of A from B using super keyword and I am getting the output. But super keyword should restrict access to private fields and methods.
What is the reason for this behaviour?

```
public class C
{
    public static class A 
    {
        private int a = 10;

        private void hello()
        {
            System.out.println("hello"); 
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A
    {   
        B() 
        {
            super.hello();
            System.out.println(super.a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();      
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
10
hello
```

Comment: It's in the same compilation unit (the same "file"), so yes, you can access private fields and methods.

Comment: I dont know anything about java, but to make the question more clear to others: what is the output (do you mean compiler warnings/errors?) and what exactly does confuse you?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: My confusion is 'why there is access to private fields and methods ?'. I was expecting an error. Hope it clarifies. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

`B` has access to private members of `A` because `B` and `A` are both **nested classes** of `C`, not because `B` is a subclass of `A`.

Access rules don't care *how* a reference is obtained, only whether the code is in a context that is allowed access. E.g. if an `A` reference is passed to a `B` method, then it can access private members. In your case, `this` and `super` are both (implicit) references to `A`.

Subclasses do not have access to private members of their superclass.

Comment: B is not an inner class of A I think. Both are inner classes for C. Hope I am not wrong. correct me once you go though the code

Comment: @Kranthi Yeah, the bad indentation of the question code made me misread that.

Answer (score 1):

Here what [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2) says:

> A class inherits from its direct superclass and direct superinterfaces
>   all the non-private fields of the superclass and superinterfaces that
>   are both accessible to code in the class and not hidden by a
>   declaration in the class.
>
> **A private field of a superclass might be accessible to a subclass -
>   for example, if both classes are members of the same class.
>   Nevertheless, a private field is never inherited by a subclass.**

This means that private fields and methods **are not inherited** but are simply visible to other class due to them being in the same class. For example the following is fine too:

```
public class C
{
    public static class A 
    {
        private int a = 10;

        private void hello()
        {
            System.out.println("hello"); 
        }
    }

    public static class B
    {   
        B() 
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.hello();
            System.out.println(a.a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();      
    }
}
```

Comment: That's useful. Thank You